# iOS to detect live face (not a photo)

Tags: ios, face

Need to add 'live face' detection into my iOS app, so that user cannot use a photo to cheat the app.

I think the detect blink in CIImage won't work it's possible user won't blink for about 5 seconds and the app need to be much more responsive than that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time

Comment: @andykkt if user is holding a photo of face, this can detect it's not live but a photo?